# Find the population mean and standard deviation

Tags: statistics

Divide the population of U.S. workers into two categories:  those who have a job in the goods-producing industries, and those who have a job in the service-producing industries.  Among all workers, sixteen percent have a job in the goods-producing industries. For these workers, the mean of annual earnings equals $\$42,419$, with a standard deviation of $\$35,572$. Among all workers, the remaining eighty-four percent have a job in the service-producing industries. For these workers, the mean of annual earnings equals $\$36,976$, with a standard deviation of $\$31,247$. Find the mean and standard deviation of annual earnings among all workers in the population.

Is this the correct answer:

Pop mean $(.16 * 42,419) + (.84 * 36,976) = 37,846.88$

Pop StdDev $(.16 * 35,572) + (.84 * 31,247) = 31,939$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let $X$ be the income of a randomly chosen worker in the goods-producing sector, and let $Y$ be the income of a randomly chosen worker in the service-producing sector. Then the income $W$ of a randomly chosen worker is given by
$$W=(0.16)X+(0.84)Y.$$
It follows that 
$$E(W)=(0.16)E(X)+(0.84)E(Y).$$
If we (reasonably) assume independence then
$$\text{Var}(W)=(0.16)^2\text{Var}(X)+(0.84)^2\text{Var}(Y).$$
For the standard deviation calculation, use the fact that the standard deviation is the square root of the variance.

Answer (score 0):

Your calculation for the mean is fine. But you can't just take a weighted average of standard deviations and expect to get the standard deviation for the population.

You need the square root of the pooled variance.